# Graphdb.js Node.js - Node Server Authentication with GraphDB

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, graphdb

I am aware that GraphDB itself provides several ways of authentication. Let's say I lock access to the GraphDB server and let only users with credentials access it. Let's say I create an authorized user with username and password.

I am using Node.js and in particular graphdb.js to establish an insecure connection. But how do I add the authentication between the communication from node server and graphdb server ? The documentation says:

> If the library is going to be used against a secured server, then all
>   API calls must be authenticated by sending an http authorization
>   header with a token which is obtained after a call to
>   rest/login/user_name with a password provided as a specific header. In
>   case the server requires that requests should be authenticated, then
>   in the ServerClientConfig and RepositoryClientConfig must be
>   configured the username and password which to be used for the
>   authentication. If those are provided, then the client assumes that
>   authentication is mandatory and the login with the provided
>   credentials is performed automatically before the first API call.
>   After a successful login, user details which are received and the auth
>   token are stored in the AuthenticationService. From that moment on,
>   with every API call is sent also an authorization header with the
>   token as value. If the token expires, then the first API call will be
>   rejected with an http error with status 401. The client handles this
>   automatically by re-login the user with the same credentials, updates
>   the stored token and retries the API call. This behavior is the
>   default and can be changed if the ServerClientConfig or
>   RepositoryClientConfig are configured with keepAlive=false.

So what are the coding steps with sample code that need to be followed. I have not seen an example somewhere doing so. Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from what @Konstantin Petrov said, I'd mention also that native authentication with graphdbjs is a feature which is still work in progress. You can follow the [PR](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb.js/pull/28) There will be added examples as well. Until then, one can workaround this by issuing a login request and use the authorization token returned with the response to create a RDFRepositoryClient instance configured with the authorization header and the token. An example for this is given below.

```
const {RepositoryClientConfig, RDFRepositoryClient} = require('graphdb').repository;
const {RDFMimeType} = require('graphdb').http;
const {SparqlJsonResultParser} = require('graphdb').parser;
const {GetQueryPayload, QueryType} = require('graphdb').query;
const axios = require('axios');

axios.post('http://localhost:7200/rest/login/admin', null, {
    headers: {
        'X-GraphDB-Password': 'root'
    }
}).then(function(token) {
    const readTimeout = 30000;
    const writeTimeout = 30000;
    const repositoryClientConfig = new RepositoryClientConfig(['http://localhost:7200/repositories/testrepo'], {
        'authorization': token.headers.authorization
    }, '', readTimeout, writeTimeout);
    const repositoryClient = new RDFRepositoryClient(repositoryClientConfig);
    repositoryClient.registerParser(new SparqlJsonResultParser());

    const payload = new GetQueryPayload()
        .setQuery('select * where {?s ?p ?o}')
        .setQueryType(QueryType.SELECT)
        .setResponseType(RDFMimeType.SPARQL_RESULTS_JSON)
        .setLimit(100);
    return repositoryClient.query(payload);
})    
.then(function(stream) {
    // here is the query response stream
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log('error', error);
});
```

Comment: I just commented there what is the status or a way to do it outside graphdbjs. But I m not sure I fully understand how to transform curl commands to node.js commands

Comment: so inside the "//use the token to configure...." I should put something like the below code and do what I want insdie there ?
router.get('/getallids', (req, res) => {
const repositoryClientConfig = new RepositoryClientConfig(['localhost:7200/repositories/V2'], {'Authorization': token}, '', readTimeout, writeTimeout);
    server.getRepository('V2',repositoryClientConfig).then(repository => { 
        repository.registerParser(new SparqlJsonResultParser());  
        const payload = new GetQueryPayload()

Comment: I get an error by doing so:
(node:14014) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 401
(node:14014) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14014) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: I connect to server and repository with the token but shouldn't I send it somehow within the query I want to perform when security is on and free access is off ?

Comment: Hi @Evan I did some investigation on the topic and here is what I found. Currently it's not possible to configure the ServerClient with some headers and have them passed with the requests. I have created an issue about that [here](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb.js/issues/66) and I've to thank you for pointing me to that direction :).
Now on your problem. If you don't need the ServerClient for anything else than obtaining RDFRepositoryClient instance, then I'd suggest you to just create it directly.

Comment: I think it might be a return statement I never had instead I started a stream inside. Your latest suggestion works like a charm with security on and free access off. Thank you Svilen (?)

Comment: and what If I wanted to handle SSL connections with axios ? I already have configured my graphdb instance

Answer (score 1):

When security is enabled you have to authorize the request by passing JWT token.
To receive a JWT token you can send a request as user admin. All examples are with curl for simplicity, but the idea would be the same.

```
POST 'http://localhost:7200/rest/login/admin' -H 'X-GraphDB-Password: root' --compressed
```

the returned header includes the JWT token:

```
-H 'Authorization: GDB eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZEF0IjoxNTQwODA1MTQ2MTE2fQ==.K0mo2dSa/Gw+AR995qTrsA1zJGwlfOVEaIokZnhINh0='
```

You can use the token in the next requests:

```
curl 'http://localhost:7200/rest/monitor/query/count' -H 'Authorization: GDB eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZEF0IjoxNTQwODA1MTQ2MTE2fQ==.K0mo2dSa/Gw+AR995qTrsA1zJGwlfOVEaIokZnhINh0=' -H 'X-GraphDB-Repository: news' --compressed
```

Comment: I m not familiar with how to transform curl commands into nodejs commands, although I get the mentality of your commands. Maybe a native js code or node.js code would make it clearer to me. I am a nodejs newcomer and event the common things are not quite common for me